# Scramble / descramble Mturk worker IDs to protect their anonymity

Tags: excel, mechanicalturk

I'm a requester on Mturk. I have posted some academic surveys on Mturk and I wish to make my data accessible online. Each row in my data corresponds to the responses of one Mturk worker. The row also contains the Mturk ID of that worker. These IDs look something like this: A4DAQF3ZHHBFIX. I have 599 different IDs. 
I want to make a function in Excel that converts these IDs into a different text, to protect workers' anonymity. Obviously different IDs should correspond to different new IDs. Any advice?

thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Invisibility is the best security. Why not drop the IDs completely and just publish the data with the rows scrambled? Presumably you will retain your own copy of the data and don't have to worry about being able to recover the data from what you publish.

You could do something like this:

1) Create a new column

2) In that column enter the formula =RAND() and copy it down through the 599 rows with your data

3) Copy these random numbers and paste them back in place with a paste special/ paste as values

4) Sort your data according to this new column.

5) Copy your workbook, deleting the ID column and this new column

6) Publish the resulting thing, perhaps with a disclaimer that the rows appear in randomized order

Comment: Hi. I've thought about this, but the reason why I want a 1-to-1 function for mturk IDs -> new IDs is that some people entered the survey twice, i.e., I have duplicates. I have a script showing how I removed these people and I want to share this as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of work, but you can encrypt the user MTURK IDs in Excel (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQYLZ5IK1Zw for an example of how to do this.

It is easy to run all of the IDs through the encryption sheet using Data Tables.  See http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/data-tables.html for an example of how to do this.

Comment: That video was quite nice, thanks for pointing it out -- but I fear that it would be a bad idea to use it in the intended application (at least without substantial tweaking). It describes a simple Caesar shift -- the least secure of the already insecure substitution ciphers. A single person who knows their own ID and can identify their row in the published results can determine the translation factor in the video and hence decrypt all of the other IDs. With hundreds of people there is a decent chance that at least some of them know how to solve simple cryptograms.